# javascript subtract(-) keycode

Tags: javascript, keycode, subtraction

ok, i need my code to check if minus/subtract/- was pressed, if it was pressed i want an alert box to pop. i tried with both `109` and `189` key codes but i still don't get the desired result. although i press `"-"` i don't get that alert box

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The JavaScript **charCodes**, which you test for during a keypress event, are [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters).  109 is the correct **keyCode**, if used in a keydown or keyup event.

"-" has a **charCode** of 45.

Comment: thanks, where can i find a complete list of the javascript keycodes? i found one or two but there i found "-" as 109 and 189

Comment: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Comment: ok, i fount a good one :P http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/very-helpful-key-codes-list-72985.html

Comment: Why worry about the actual value of the character code? Why not just convert it to a string using `String.fromCharCode`?

Comment: Because it's quite a bit faster.

Comment: Fair enough, although unless you have loads of keypress event handlers I think it's unlikely to make much of a difference.

Comment: It's one of those things that may be premature optimization, but why knowingly degrade the performance of a heavily called function if you don't have to.  If readability is an issue, you can always comment it without impacting performance.

Answer (score 13):

1.event.keyCode = 109 is '-' on numpad

2.event.keyCode = 189 is'-' in alphabate keybord key on chrome

3.event.keyCode= 173 is '-' in alphabate keybord key on firefox & on chrome 173 keycord is Mute On|Off

Comment: I appreciate your insight to how Firefox handles `keyCode 189`. Seems silly to me that there aren't set standards for stuff like this. `keyCode 189` is a `-` on every browser I test with except Firefox. Reminds me of how IE likes to be a browser trailblazer, regardless of the incompatibility issues that arise from their wild slinging of the machete. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 9):

Don't do this in a `keydown` event handler - you put yourself at the mercy of different browsers' ideas about key codes and potential variation between key codes for different keyboard types. Do it in a `keypress` event and then you can get the character code instead, which is what you actually want.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if (charStr == "-") {
        alert("Minus!");
    }
};
```

All the information you could ever need about JavaScript key events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Comment: Actually `keydown` is a better answer than `keypress`. If you look at the compatibility list (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) `keypress` didn't work in some older versions of Firefox

Comment: @fudgey: I think you're misreading those compatibility tables. The `charCode` and `which` properties of the `keypress` event have been happily reporting character codes correctly in Firefox since I first tried it, which I think was pre-1.0. What you may be picking out from those tables is that Firefox always reports 0 for the `keyCode` property of `keypress` events, which really isn't a problem here.

Comment: @TimDown Thank you. Chrome worked with onkeydown and key codes 109 and 189 but Firefox did not. After switching to the onkeypress and to the method you described, detecting '-' works well everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

You can discover keyCodes this way:

- [Javascript Char Codes (Key Codes)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160603143836/http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-key-codes)
- [Detecting keystrokes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html)

Comment: first link is not valid anymore

Answer (score 6):

Post some code. This works for me:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 109 || e.keyCode === 189) {
        alert('minus sign pressed');
    }
};
```

Full list of key codes here: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx

Comment: Don't do this in the `keydown` event. See my answer.

Comment: 189 is not the minus sign for all keyboard layouts.

Comment: In the example page the keyboard layout is english. That's not the case everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

People are moving away from `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode` due to inconsistent implementations across browsers. Instead, use `event.code`. This is a `string` field.

Most browsers support `Array.includes`, so I tend to do the following:

```js
if (['-', 'Minus', 'NumpadSubtract'].includes(e.code)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: In Firefox and Chrome, it was necessary to change `.includes(e.code)` to `.includes(e.originalEvent.code)` when used in conjunction with `keydown`.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this works for you, It detects users pressed keys and if it's the one your looking for it displays the alert, you may change the actual key to be any other key.

```
function detectSubstract(e)
{
var evtobj=window.event? event : e //distinguish between IE's explicit event object (window.event) and Firefox's implicit.
var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)

    if (actualkey=="-")
    {
        alert('You pressed the minus key')
    }
}
document.onkeypress=detectSubstract
```