# jQuery regex can match numbers, but not hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So, I would like to limit an input field to only allow numbers and hyphens.  I'm not interested in changing my methodology, but would like to understand why my regex matches numbers but not hyphens.

Regex:

```
/[^0-9-]/g
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abriggs/7G6JD/

Comment: Please escape hyphens. Maybe /[^0-9\-]/g

Comment: @Ethan The last hyphen does not need to be escaped.

Comment: +1 since it was a good question . In future , try to give descriptive code in question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with keycode of `-` ,

[keycode of `-` is `189`  or `109` .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898129/javascript-subtract-keycode)

But
  `String.fromCharCode(189)`  is `½`

`String.fromCharCode(109)`  is `m`

You can use the following code :

```
function numbersOnly(number, allowDash) {
    // Filter non-digits/dash from input value.
    console.log(number);
    if (allowDash) {
        number = number.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, '');
    } else {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        number = number.replace(/\D/, '');
    }
    return number;
}

$(function(){

    // Do not allow non-numeric characters in bill zip code
    $('#billZip').keydown(function(e) {
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if (e.keyCode != 8 && e.keyCode != 37 && e.keyCode != 39) {
              if(e.keyCode ===189||e.keyCode ===109)
                 if (numbersOnly(String.fromCharCode(45), true) != "")
                    return true;
                 else 
                     return false

            if (numbersOnly(String.fromCharCode(e.which), true) != "")
                return true;
            else return false
        }
    });

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/KTgam/)**

Comment: Thanks, accepted your answer as it provides a complete solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding simple console lines will show the error

```
function numbersOnly(number, allowDash) {
    console.log("In numbersOnly);
    // Filter non-digits/dash from input value.
    if (allowDash) { 
        console.log("1:", number);
        number = number.replace(/[^0-9\-]/g, '');
        console.log(2:", number);
    } else {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        number = number.replace(/\D/, '');
    }
    return number;
}
```

Type in `1`

```
In numbersOnly
1: 1
2: 1
```

Type in `-`

```
In numbersOnly
1: ½ 
2:
```

So your problem is with the line `String.fromCharCode(e.which)`

Comment: Thanks, your'e right.  +1, but accepted answer from Sujith PS because he provided a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to have the hyphen as the **FIRST** or **LAST** character within the character class such as this:

```
[-0-9] or [0-9-]
```

However, you are using a `"^"` which negates everything in the character class, so if you only want hyphens and numbers you should not have the caret.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: Fixed to add both options.

Comment: Something might be wrong with your code, but the regex itself tests out.

Comment: The regex might be fine alone, but if it doesn't solve the OP's problem then it's not really a valid answer. Your solution shouldn't just point out part of the problem, it should fully answer all parts of the question and factor in the full code provided.

Comment: There's already an accepted answer so no need at this point.  The fiddle shows that they needed to add some more keycodes.