# Restrict to input minus symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to restrict user to input `minus` symbol. How to do it useing following **jQuery** I have got?

```
$("#Age").keydown(function (e) {

            // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter  
            if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || $.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110]) !== -1 ||              
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ($(this).val().length <= 2 || (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }); // end of $
```

Comment: User experience tip: Never, ever, *ever* hard-block someone from entering whatever they want. Validate, certainly, but do not block input.

Comment: @RiZKiT Actually I was thinking `<input type="number" />` ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898129/javascript-subtract-keycode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[ASCII key codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters)**

**Minus symbol ASCII value is 45**

```
$("#Age").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 45) { //it does't allow user to enter minus(-) symbol
    ..
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}); // end of $
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol just given hint, `syntax`