# Input should allow numbers and dash character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written jquery for allowing numbers and dash - from being entered

```
$('.no-special-characters').keydown(function(e){  
  if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode == 45) {
    return true; 
  }  else {
    return false;
  } 
});
```

It does not work accordingly. It allows only numbers to be accepted.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you want to control what's in an input, you should check characters instead of the keyboard event. Because there are ways to enter characters in an input without explicitly typing it, for example pasting in the input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**Updated** with backspace support

Allow the keycode of `189`

```js
$('.no-special-characters').keydown(function(e) {
   var key =  e.keyCode|e.which;
      console.log(key) //check the key value in your console.log
      if (key >= 48 && key <= 57 || key == 45 || key == 189 ||key == 8){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="no-special-characters">
```

Comment: It is not working  and it is blocking backspace also

Comment: thanks for answer... there is one problem.. It does not allow - character... it should allow - character but not _ character

Comment: Ya.In your question `numbers and dash - from being`, you are mention only the number and `-` that's all.Not mention with spl character

Comment: Please help for - character

Comment: Lets check my upadted answer.remove the ctrl and shift key validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154892/discussion-between-nida-and-prasad).

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```js
$('.no-special-characters').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 || e.keyCode == 189) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="no-special-characters">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution

```js
$('.no-special-characters').keydown(function(e){  
  if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || e.keyCode == 189) {
    return true; 
  } else {
    return false;
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="no-special-characters" type="text" />
```

Usually combine the `keyCode` from `48 to 57` & then the next keyCode condition.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> e.keyCode = 109 is '-' on numpad
>
> e.keyCode = 189 is '-' in alphabate keybord key on chrome
>
> e.keyCode = 173 is '-' in alphabate keyboard key on firefox & on chrome 173 keycord is Mute On|Off

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473259/7467567)

Maybe this helps you, because using only `e.keyCode == 189` (as some answers say) wont work in Firefox.

You can see, what `keyCode` your key presses return here: [Link](https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

**Edit:** You can also use regular expressions. Then there is no need to add keyCodes for different browsers:

```
$('.no-special-characters').keypress(function(e){  
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which)
    var pattern = /^[0-9\-]+$/;
    if (!(pattern.test(txt) || e.keyCode == 8)){
            return false;
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drews/9g2kh65x/)