# Cannot read negative sign onscan.js

Tags: javascript

I am using [this](https://github.com/axenox/onscan.js/) `onscan.js` package to scan barcode `test-123`. However it is reading it as `test123`.

When I use my scanner gun in a regular notepad, I do get `test-123`

I looked into their main github file and found this comment:

```
     * By default, only the follwing key codes are taken into account
     * - 48-90 (letters and regular numbers)
     * - 96-105 (numeric keypad numbers)
     * - 106-111 (numeric keypad operations)
     * 
     * All other keys will yield empty strings!
```

The code also contains:

```
switch (true) {
    case iCode >= 48 && iCode <= 90: // numbers and letters
    case iCode >= 106 && iCode <= 111: // operations on numeric keypad (+, -, etc.)
        if (oEvent.key !== undefined && oEvent.key !== '') {
            return oEvent.key;
        }
        var sDecoded = String.fromCharCode(iCode);
        switch (oEvent.shiftKey) {
            case false: sDecoded = sDecoded.toLowerCase(); break;
            case true: sDecoded = sDecoded.toUpperCase(); break;
        }
    return sDecoded;
        case iCode >= 96 && iCode <= 105: // numbers on numeric keypad
            return 0+(iCode-96);
        }
```

I changed the code to this, to add `045` code for `-` but it still does not work:

```
switch (true) {
    case (iCode >= 48 && iCode <= 90) || iCode == 045: // numbers and letters
    case (iCode >= 106 && iCode <= 111) || iCode == 045 : // operations on numeric keypad (+, -, etc.)
        if (oEvent.key !== undefined && oEvent.key !== '') {
            return oEvent.key;
        }
                
        var sDecoded = String.fromCharCode(iCode);
        switch (oEvent.shiftKey) {
           case false: sDecoded = sDecoded.toLowerCase(); break;
           case true: sDecoded = sDecoded.toUpperCase(); break;
        }
    return sDecoded;
        case iCode >= 96 && iCode <= 105: // numbers on numeric keypad
            return 0+(iCode-96);
        }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the documentation in the link you sent. I don't know if you implemented this already in someway.

> This should work for the vast majority of cases. However, if you encounter strange extra characters in the codes read or miss some characters (like hypens), you can override the default decoding algorithm by specifying a custom keyCodeMapper like this:

```
onScan.attachTo(document, {
  keyCodeMapper: function(oEvent) {
    
    // your hyphen-minus code is 45
    if (oEvent.which == 'your_special_key_code') {
        return 'xxx';
    }
    // Fall back to the default decoder in all other cases
    return onScan.decodeKeyEvent(oEvent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this. But it is returning 'xxx' 

`keyCodeMapper: function(oEvent) {
    
        // your hyphen-minus code is 45
        if (oEvent.which == 45) {
            return 'xxx';
        }
        // Fall back to the default decoder in all other cases
        return onScan.decodeKeyEvent(oEvent);
    }`

I also tried using the 

` onKeyDetect: function(iKeyCode){ // output all potentially relevant key events - great for debugging!
        console.log('Pressed: ' + iKeyCode);
    }`

but keycode 45 is not even there

Comment: @goxarad784 The `xxx` is supposed to just be a placeholder, you are supposed to change it to return the value you want.

Comment: I am sorry I meant to say "it is not returning 'xxx'"

Comment: @goxarad784 So the same scanner worked in some situations, but not other times? When does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's maybe a bit late, but I runned into the same problem. The iCode you need to add is not "45", but "189" (if you use Google Chrome)
I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473259/6202903. I've changed the code on line 4

```
var iCode = this._getNormalizedKeyNum(oEvent);
switch (true) {
    case iCode >= 48 && iCode <= 90: // numbers and letters
    case (iCode >= 106 && iCode <= 111) || iCode == 45 || iCode == 173 || iCode == 189: // operations on numeric keypad (+, -, etc.)
        if (oEvent.key !== undefined && oEvent.key !== '') {
            return oEvent.key;
        }

        var sDecoded = String.fromCharCode(iCode);
        switch (oEvent.shiftKey) {
            case false: sDecoded = sDecoded.toLowerCase(); break;
            case true: sDecoded = sDecoded.toUpperCase(); break;
        }
        return sDecoded;
    case iCode >= 96 && iCode <= 105: // numbers on numeric keypad
        return 0+(iCode-96);
}
return '';
```